# Lambda with parameter in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I want to write `TextWatcher` for several `EditText`s. In any of them I want to assign `EditText` value to a variable. Like this:

```
var variable: String? = null

private inner class CodeTextWatcher : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        variable = s?.toString()
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    }
}
```

For several `EditText`s I want to write something like:

```
private inner class CodeTextWatcher(private val method: (String?) -> Unit) : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        method(s?.toString())
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    }
}
```

and call it:

```
textWatcher1 = CodeTextWatcher {variable1 = s}
textWatcher2 = CodeTextWatcher {variable2 = s}
```

But I cannot write `s` here and want to access `s` from `afterTextChanged(s: Editable?)`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
textWatcher1 = CodeTextWatcher { s -> variable1 = s }
textWatcher2 = CodeTextWatcher { s -> variable2 = s }
```

Or in this case, maybe even

```
textWatcher1 = CodeTextWatcher { variable1 = it }
textWatcher2 = CodeTextWatcher { variable2 = it }
```

?